# ownCloud android app compilation error

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors, owncloud

I am trying to compile ownCloud app for android devices. However i get this error:

```
AuthenticatorActivity.java:228: error: cannot find symbol R.string.error_cant_bind_tooperations_service,
                                                                  ^
symbol: variable error_cant_bind_to_operations_service
location: class string
```

I haven't edited any files. Here is the script file : http://pastebin.com/508yDrGc